# UITableViewCell swiped but delete button doesn't appear

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ios-simulator

This is odd.  I'm right swiping a UITableViewCell in the iPad simulator.  Even though the event below fires and the swipedCell is not nil, the Delete button doesn't appear.  Actually, it appears-but only sometimes.  I never get a bad access or a sigbart.

Here's the code:

```
- (void)handleSwipeFrom:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)recognizer 
{   
    if (userListSwipeRightRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        CGPoint swipeLocation = [userListSwipeRightRecognizer locationInView:self.outletView];
        NSIndexPath *swipedIndexPath = [self.outletView indexPathForRowAtPoint:swipeLocation];
        UITableViewCell* swipedCell = [self.outletView cellForRowAtIndexPath:swipedIndexPath];
        [swipedCell setEditing:YES];

    }   
}
```

Is this just a simulator issue or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Is there any reason why you handle the swipe gesture yourself, rather than let UITableView do it automagically?

Comment: I'm going to also show an "edit" button in an accessory cell when a cell is swiped.  What I'm doing may not be the best way.  This is my first app.

Answer (score 10):

If you simply want to enable swipe-to-delete on your table, there is a much easier way to do it. Implement `tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath:` in your data source and the table view will automatically show the delete button when a cell is swiped.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
}
```

Comment: I think that actually deletes the rows.  I'm just trying to get the delete button to appear....

Comment: The table view will automatically show the button if that method is defined. The method will be called when the button is clicked. If you don't actually want to delete the button, then don't call deleteForRowsAtIndexPaths: inside the method.

Comment: great hint, I was also first trying to get the button visible on swipe, thinking that I don't need to be able to "commit" the action yet... but simply implementing an empty methods makes the swipe work

Answer (score 0):

If you defined your UITableView in your header, then try:

```
 swipedCell = [self.outletView cellForRowAtIndexPath:swipedIndexPath];
```

Comment: I'm already doing that in the OP code.  Did you mean something else or am I misunderstanding you?

Answer (score -1):

If you use a custom cell and override `setEditing`, you must call the super method or your delete controls will not be drawn.

```
- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];
}
```